# HTML Form Currency Field - Auto Format Currency to 2 Decimal and Max Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Day,

I've got a deposit field on a form that has currency auto-formatted to include 2 decimals (i.e. a user types 2500 and the field shows 25.00). However, the script I have written completely ignores the maxlength that I've included in the html. See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny2pj7kq/23/) here. I have tried various jQuery options to try to enforce the limit such as:

```
$('input[name=amount]').attr('maxlength',9);
```

Here's the script I'm using on my page:

```
amountValue = "";

$(function() {
  $(".mib").unbind().keydown(function(e) {
    //handle backspace key
    if (e.keyCode == 8 && amountValue.length > 0) {
      amountValue = amountValue.slice(0, amountValue.length - 1); //remove last digit
      $(this).val(formatNumber(amountValue));
    } else {
      var key = getKeyValue(e.keyCode);
      if (key) {
        amountValue += key; //add actual digit to the input string
        $(this).val(formatNumber(amountValue)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

  function getKeyValue(keyCode) {
    if (keyCode > 57) { //also check for numpad keys
      keyCode -= 48;
    }
    if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
      return String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    }
  }

  function formatNumber(input) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
      return "0.00"; //if the input is invalid just set the value to 0.00
    }
    var num = parseFloat(input);
    return (num / 100).toFixed(2); //move the decimal up to places return a X.00 format
  }
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="tel" id="amount" maxlength="10"  name="amount" class="full mib" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?$" title="Please enter a valid number">
```

Comment: have you tried just doing this in html. Something like: `<input type="number" pattern="/^\d+([,.]\d+)?$/" step=".01" required>` Can we see your html? Are you trying to format it before sending it off somewhere or are you just trying to validate?

Comment: Updated with HTML

Comment: What if the user wanted to type in $2500?

Comment: also why is your `type="tel"`. See my above comment for proper html. Also instead of your custom script, pass the value to the answer I left below

Comment: The way the script works, the user can type in any number. if the user wanted 2500.00, they would type in 250000 and the script plugs in the decimal.

The type=tel was a hold over from a previous iteration so the user could/can type the decimal if they choose. My requirement changed to the auto format.

Comment: `type='number'` and `step='.01'` will net you the same result

Comment: See the second part of my answer for a solution

Comment: The input field has to show the decimal as the user types.

Comment: Please see the second part of my answer below. Just add that return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do money formatting. Try something like this:

```
var convertStringToUSDFormat = function (value) {
    // Create our number formatter.
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    });

    return formatter.format(value);
}
```

If you still want to use your script, add this return:

```
if (key) {
    amountValue += key; //add actual digit to the input string
    if(amountValue.length >=10) return;
    $(this).val(formatNumber(amountValue)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
 }
```